# '$eq' is not working with arrays in dates in mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

'$eq' is not working with dates. Can Anyone help me on this. 
So what I'm trying to do is I want to search documents based on multiple dates. There is a startdate field on the document that I want to search against. If I give a plain query, it will retrive the doc. But when I will give the array of dates in '$eq', it is not working. Can Someone point out the mistake or reformat this query to work.

```
db.getCollection('campaigngrid').find({
    startdate: { '$eq': [ ISODate('2021-02-05'), ISODate('2021-02-12') ] },
//    startdate: ISODate('2021-02-05'),
    active: true
})
```

So I've double check the query. And the document is also there. When I just search with simple query, it retrieves the docs(which I just commented).
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried any other [Comparison Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) other than `$eq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to find where date is ISODate('2021-02-05') or ISODate('2021-02-12')

But your problem is

```
 $eq: [ISODate('2021-02-05'), ISODate('2021-02-12')]
```

will find where startdate = [ISODate('2021-02-05'), ISODate('2021-02-12')];

**To find where startdate equals at least one of your dates something like this:**

```
db.getCollection('campaigngrid').find({
    startdate: { '$in': [ ISODate('2021-02-05'), ISODate('2021-02-12') ] },
    active: true
})
```

Comment: Your welcome @YashJaiswal . This things happens to all of us.